# Check if event is already in calendar

Tags: android, events, insert

I use google-java-client-library v3.

Know I want to create events by code. This is working fine so far. But when i run my code a second time, I get exactly the same events a second time. And so on.

Know my questions:

1. Is it possible to check if an event with the same parameters allready exsists or not? I dont have any IDs when the event isnt inserted.
2. Can I get an EventID before its inserted?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/
I believe its possible this way.